# Unable to install Ubuntu on a Windows 11 virtual machine (VMware Fusion Pro 13, Apple M2 chip)

Tags: vmware-fusion, m2

This is the error I got when I tried to open Ubuntu.

```
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370102
Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.
For information please visit https://aka.ms/enablevirtualization
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: If you're trying to install Ubuntu on a nested virtual machine that explains the error message because there is no BIOS in a virtual machine.

Comment: ok, that explains everything, thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the error url to enable nested virtualization?  Set-VMProcessor -VMName <VMName> -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true

Comment: @ubfan1 Yes, this is the error i got. 'Set-VMProcessor : Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual machine with name "windows11".'

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to install Ubuntu on a nested virtual machine that explains the error message because there is no BIOS in a virtual machine.